# Chilly peppers planting

Tags: peppers

I planted more then 50 chilly pepper plants but just one of them gave blossoms. Others are growing well but have no blossoms.

The soil is mixed sand soil, for indoor planting, about 6 hours under the sun, given 2 times nitrogen, PH of soil is 5.8, water 2 or 3 days.

Comment: Feeding Nitrogen pushes leaf growth at the expense of flowers. In time, the plants will want to flower.